# Spell-check two languages at once in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I often write in English, but the default language is set to Norwegian making most English incorrect. Some is still correct, but it is annoying. I do not want to manually switch between languages so I want to either check it automatically or check both at once. Is either possible, in which case how?

**To clarify:** Is there any way to check for what language is in writing and spell check that language automatically? I do not want to change manually and I don't want the language to be fixed.

Comment: You can try using Right click menu in the middle of the misspelled word if it is the same language you can see corrected word or choose language and choose your language then spelling and you will see the correction

Comment: "I do not want to manually switch between languages" it says in unedited form